# How to handle ICollection<> field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I have a big trouble handling the ICollection field on this model

This is my model

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    public RegisterModel() 
    {
        this.Servicios = new HashSet<Servicio>();
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="El nombre de usuario es requerido.")]
    [Display(Name = "Usuario")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La contraseña es obligatoria.")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe tener al menos {2} caracteres de longitud.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirmar contraseña.")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "La contraseña y la confirmacion no coinciden.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Seleccione los servicios que desea agregar al usuario")]
    [Display(Name="Servicio")]
    public ICollection<Servicio> Servicios { get; set; } //This field
}
```

Now what I want to achieve it's create a EditorTemplate for `Servicio` which actually I did it, but the problem it's that in main view that's strongly type for `RegisterModel` I don't how to passed each Servicio from the ICollection<> to my EditorTemplate I tried like this but it doesn't work

```
@model SodexoSAT.Models.RegisterModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "No se Pudo crear la cuenta. Por favor corrija los errores e inténtelo de nuevo.")
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Información de la cuenta</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Servicios)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Servicios) <--doesn't work
                @Html.EditorForModel(m => Model.Servicios) <--doesn't work
                @Html.EditorForModel(Model.Servicios) <--doesn't work too
            </div>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Crear Usuario" class="botonAtento" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

}

Comment: you have trouble but what is the exact problem || Error that you are experiencing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652457/asp-net-mvc-problem-with-editortemplate-for-icollectiont-mapped-to-enum already has this same post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Servicios)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Servicios) <--doesn't work
            @Html.EditorForModel(m => Model.Servicios) <--doesn't work
            @Html.EditorForModel(Model.Servicios) <--doesn't work too
        </div>
    </div>
```

with

```
@foreach(var service in m.Servicios)
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(service)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(service) <--doesn't work
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

That way, you'll have the editor (with the attached label) per each service in `Model.Services`.

Comment: -1 This will generate duplicate element ids for your controls and will not work when you want to post the data to a form (and is invalid html as well). Imho not a good idea.

Comment: There are even deeper reasons for why not to do in the way i suggested. I just thought of something else when writing this answer.