# Html.EditorFor a child object in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code in my view:

```
@foreach (var parent in Model.Parents)
        {      
            @foreach (var child in parent.Children)
                { 

                 @Html.TextAreaFor(c => child.name)

                }                   
        }
```

Other textareas in the form are saving fine, but when submit the form, the POST method in my controller gets a viewModel with a null Parents field.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a `foreach` loop if you want the collections to bind. You have to use `for` loops:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Parents.Count; i++) {
    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Parents[i].Children.Count; j++) {
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Parents[i].Children[j].name)
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use an Editor Template for Parents (and even another for Children). This would require you setting up a template for a Parent model and putting it in your EditorTemplates folder, then calling it like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Parents)
```

MVC will take care of the Enumeration and binding. The same could then be done for the Children list.

Here is an mvc tutorial on using them (I couldn't find an mvc4 version):  http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

Comment: Thank you Simon.  I'm getting an error because Children is an ICollection, and all I have is Parents in my viewModel.  Any idea how I can "ToList" everything in Parents, or somehow resolve this?

Comment: Either change to an IList, or use the editor templates then. Editor templates work fine with IEnumerables. Check this answer for an idea of using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652457/asp-net-mvc-problem-with-editortemplate-for-icollectiont-mapped-to-enum?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I would have to use two templates then, right?  One for parent, one for child?

Comment: If Parents is a list, you could use a for loop for that, then an editor for the children collection. If they are both ICollection or IEnumerable, you will need to use an editor template for each.